# how to create a cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, pssnapin

I have written my program in c# .net. I want to convert it in to a powershell cmdlet. I was instructed to use pssnapin and getproc programs. Can anyone plz help me out..

Regards
Arun

Comment: Is there any reason that you **have not accepted** any answer to you questions?

Answer (score 4):

To create a PowerShell cmdlet I would recommend you read [Easy Windows PowerShell cmdlet development and debugging](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/03/easy-windows-powershell-cmdlet-development-and-debugging.aspx) by Bart De Smet (B#) it's a great walk through for creating and debugging cmdlet's (Does what it says on the tin!)

Also I've found Professional Windows PowerShell Programming, ISBN 978-0470173930, (ISBN-10) 0470173939 very good for creating cmdlets and providers.

Answer (score 2):

So, here's the PSCmdlet-Class[from medata], that you can inherit from.

```
namespace System.Management.Automation
{
    public abstract class PSCmdlet : Cmdlet
    {
        protected PSCmdlet();

        public PSHost Host { get; }
        public CommandInvocationIntrinsics InvokeCommand { get; }
        public ProviderIntrinsics InvokeProvider { get; }
        public InvocationInfo MyInvocation { get; }
        public string ParameterSetName { get; }
        public SessionState SessionState { get; }

        public PathInfo CurrentProviderLocation(string providerId);
        public Collection<string> GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(string path, out ProviderInfo provider);
        public string GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(string path);
        public object GetVariableValue(string name);
        public object GetVariableValue(string name, object defaultValue);
    }
}
```

In order to get your cmdlets loaded, you need to sign them additionally, because Powershell does not execute not signed code.

Comment: by default... feel free to use Set-ExecutionPolicy to allow it at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Install windows powershell template thereby u will get the pssnapin program, using that you can convert your .cs file into a dll. Then search for getproc program in msdn. I don't remember exactly but there will be a method which will be executed at the first. you call your dll file in that method. I don't remeber the code, but this is the procedure to do.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article, [Creating PowerShell Cmdlets in VB 2005](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/controls/vb_shell/article.php/c13743/). It uses VB 2005, but the process is the same for C#.

Full disclosure, I wrote the article, but I do not get paid by you looking at it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check also http://blogs.msdn.com/daiken/.  In particular all the months from February 2007 to June 2007.  You'll find the Visual Studio template link (for 2005, also works in Express), and several examples/labs.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerTime project (http://code.google.com/p/powertime/) is open source and it implements a number of cmdlets. Good for a demo to get you going.